# Excel VBA convert Date with time

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 cells with time data that format as follows:

```
"A1" = Sep 01 2018 00:01:33.707 
"A2" = Sep 01 2018 00:01:49.917
```

I need to create a button and method within excel VBA that will set "A3" cell to true if the time "A2" is more than "A1" by 90 seconds.
This is what i have so far but it does not work:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String

    With Worksheets("sheet5")

        str1 = .Cells(1, "A").Text
        str2 = .Cells(2, "A").Text

        'greater than 90m seconds in A3
        .Cells(3, "A") = CBool(Abs((DateValue(Left(str1, 6) & "," & Mid(str1, 7, 5)) + _
                                    TimeValue(Mid(str1, 13, 8)) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * CDbl(Right(str1, 4))) - _
                                   (DateValue(Left(str2, 6) & "," & Mid(str2, 7, 5)) + _
                                   TimeValue(Mid(str2, 13, 8)) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * CDbl(Right(str2, 4)))) > _
                                   TimeSerial(0, 0, 90))
        'actual absolute difference in A4
        .Cells(4, "A") = Abs((DateValue(Left(str1, 6) & "," & Mid(str1, 7, 5)) + _
                                    TimeValue(Mid(str1, 13, 8)) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * CDbl(Right(str1, 4))) - _
                                   (DateValue(Left(str2, 6) & "," & Mid(str2, 7, 5)) + _
                                    TimeValue(Mid(str2, 13, 8)) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * CDbl(Right(str2, 4))))
    End With End Sub
```

The above gives error because Date functions works with system Locale, which in my case is Hebrew, while the Data is in English.

Another way that could help is to convert all the column "A" (which holds the dates) to a system local date that can be used with Date and time functions on VBA (don't know how to do that).

Please help

Comment: Are the values in A1 and A2 real dates or strings that look like a date?

Comment: @FunThomas they are real dates from another system that exported as Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have split your task into 3 functions.

a) a helper function converts the 3 characters of the month into an integer. It looks a little clumsy, there might be other approaches but the advantage of using a large `Select Case` is it is easy to understand and easy to adapt if month names in a different language arise:

```
Function getMonthFromName(monthName As String) As Integer

    Select Case UCase(monthName)
        Case "JAN": getMonthFromName = 1
        Case "FEB": getMonthFromName = 2
        Case "MAR": getMonthFromName = 3
        Case "APR": getMonthFromName = 4
        (...)
        Case "SEP": getMonthFromName = 9
        (...)
    End Select

End Function
```

b) a function that converts the string into a date. It assumes the date format in the form you provided, but it is easily adapted if the format changes (for simplicity, the seconds are rounded)

```
Function GetDateFromString(dt As String) As Date

    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(Replace(dt, ":", " "), " ")

    Dim day As Integer, month As Integer, year As Integer
    month = getMonthFromName(CStr(tokens(0)))
    day = Val(tokens(1))
    year = Val(tokens(2))

    Dim hour As Integer, minute As Integer, second As Double
    hour = Val(tokens(3))
    minute = Val(tokens(4))
    second = Round(Val(tokens(5)), 0)

    GetDateFromString = DateSerial(year, month, day) + TimeSerial(hour, minute, second)
End Function
```

c) A function that calculated the difference of the 2 dates in seconds. A date in VBA (and many other environments) is stored as `Double`, where the Date-Part is the integer part and the date is the remainder. This makes it easy to calculate with Date values.

```
Function DateDiffInSeconds(d1 As String, d2 As String) As Long
    Dim diff As Double
    diff = GetDateFromString(d2) - GetDateFromString(d1)
    DateDiffInSeconds = diff * 24 * 60 * 60
End Function
```

**Update** to deal with milliseconds: Change the `GetDateFromString`-function. In that case, `DateDiffInSeconds` should return a `double` rather than a `long`.

```
Function GetDateFromString(dt As String) As Date

    Const MillSecPerHour As Long = 24& * 60 * 60 * 1000

    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(Replace(Replace(dt, ".", " "), ":", " "), " ")

    Dim day As Integer, month As Integer, year As Integer
    month = getMonthFromName(CStr(tokens(0)))
    day = Val(tokens(1))
    year = Val(tokens(2))

    Dim hour As Integer, minute As Integer, second As Integer, milli As Integer
    hour = Val(tokens(3))
    minute = Val(tokens(4))
    second = Val(tokens(5))
    milli = Val(tokens(6))

    GetDateFromString = DateSerial(year, month, day) _
                      + TimeSerial(hour, minute, second) _
                      + milli / MillSecPerHour
End Function
```

Comment: thank you for your excellent complete solution, it works great! I will try to make the first function faster by using an array with months names and return the index of the correct month. Is there away to include the milliseconds  into calculations as well?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show a way to deal with milliseconds.

Comment: If it is only for speed: Forget about  changing it to an array: This function is so fast that you never will be able to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating it, try this to get an idea how to do it:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String

    With Worksheets("sheet5")

        .Range("b1:e1") = Split(Range("A1"), " ")
        .Range("B2:e2") = Split(Range("A2"), " ")


End Sub
```

Comment: this does not take into considuration the Date itself (month, day or year), i need to include them as well...

Comment: No it didn't.  Sorry, but if you split your string in the suggested way, you can recreate the date using a lookup for the month value.

Comment: can you put up a complete solution please?

Comment: Use something like `=DATE(D1,MATCH(B1,{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0),C1)` to convert the string into a date, add the time value and the  rest should be simple.

Comment: I need it on VBA script since i got tons of sheets

Answer (score 0):

For your information, I've done what you are doing in a slightly different (and easier) way:

In cell B2, I put the value `13/11/2018  11:44:00`.
In cell B3, I put the value `13/11/2018  11:45:01`.
(For both cells, the cell formatting has been set to `d/mm/jjjj u:mm:ss`).

In another cell, I put following formula:

```
=IF((B3-B2)*86400>90;TRUE;FALSE)
```

The formula is based on the idea that a datetime value is set, based on the idea that one day equals 1, and there are 86400 seconds in one day.

Like this, you can calculate time differences without needing VBA.

Comment: Thanks, but i really need it on VBA since it's going to be part of a bigger macro. Also, i see that you changed the values of the Cells, i don't have an option to change it since they are imported as is, this is why i needed a convert solution...

Comment: @user1610208: my idea is based on the automatic conversion of dates. I've just entered "01/04/2014" in an Excel sheet, and it gets automatically converted to a date. If you can find a way to convert your cell values automatically to dates, your problem might be solved. Can you get rid of the downvote of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use UDF.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
    Dim mySecond As Double, t1 As Double, t2 As Double, t3 As Double
    mySecond = TimeSerial(0, 0, 90)

    With Worksheets("sheet5")
        str1 = .Cells(1, "A").Text
        str2 = .Cells(2, "A").Text
        t1 = ConvertTime(str1)
        t2 = ConvertTime(str2)
        t3 = t2 - t1
        .Cells(3, "a") = Abs(t3) >= mySecond
    End With

End Sub
Function ConvertTime(s As String)
    Dim vS
    vS = Split(s, " ")
    ConvertTime = DateValue(vS(0) & "-" & vS(1) & "-" & vS(2)) + TimeValue(Split(vS(3), ".")(0))
End Function
```